# To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function (potential async issue)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await, memory-leaks

Getting the following (common) message in my console:

**Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.**

This is a common question, I know, I've been trying to figure out where my specific problem is. Below are the original code (with the error) as well as my attempted fix (did not work, but made es-lint happy).

`setData` is a state hook, if that wasn't clear.

Original code:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isExisting) {
      const fetchData = async () => {
        const response = await refreshData();
        setData(response);
      };
      fetchData();
      // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }
  }, []);
```

Attempted Fix:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isExisting) {
      const fetchData = async () => {
        const response = await refreshData();
        setData(response);
      };
      fetchData();
      // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }
  }, [isExisting, refreshData]);
```

Comment: I definitely did do that exact search. I'm still at a loss.

Comment: The truth is the duplicate I linked doesn't seem great, I think an [Abort Controller](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController/AbortController) in the return of the useEffect is a better solution. Here's an article [Clean Up Async Requests in `useEffect` Hooks](https://dev.to/pallymore/clean-up-async-requests-in-useeffect-hooks-90h)

Comment: It's a good idea in a useEffect to keep track of mounted state, and then NOT call setState if still not mounted,  using the AbortController mentioned above is also a nice but it's not essential.   You just need something like this in your `useEffect`,  `let mounted = true;  /*do fetch*/  if (mounted) setState(); return () => mounted = false;`